# How to delete capabilities in an Xcode storyboard?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

My storyboard is unresponsive in Xcode. I came across some advice to delete the following capabilities. How do I go about doing this? Where do I access these?

```
<capability name="Aspect ratio constraints" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
    <capability name="Constraints with non-1.0 multipliers" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the storyboard source code manually(using text editor) and u can edit these they are usually at the top